# How is the print and view functions works in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

This is a convolutional neural network which I found in the web

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(500, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 64)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 500)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x)
```

and its summary

```
print(net)
Net(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 10, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (conv2): Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (conv2_drop): Dropout2d(p=0.5)
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=500, out_features=50, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=50, out_features=64, bias=True)
)
```

What is `x.view` does? Is it similar to the `Flatten` function in keras. The other query is reagarding how pytorch prints summary of a model. Eventhough the model uses two dropouts `nn.Dropout2d()` and `F.dropout`. When printing the model we can see only one `(conv2_drop): Dropout2d(p=0.5)`, why?. The last question is why pytorch  dosen't print `F.max_pool2d` layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `x.view` can do more than just flatten: It will keep the same data while reshaping the dimension. So using `x.view(batch_size, -1)`will be equivalent to `Flatten`

2) In the `__repr__`function of [`nn.Module`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L778), the elements that are printed are the modules in `self._modules.items()` which are its children.

`F.dropout`and `F.max_pool2d` are functions and not children of `nn.Module`, thus they are not layers and will not be printed. For pooling and dropout however, there is a module in `torch.nn` which you already used for the first dropout.